Proving Independence of $A_1, A_2, . . . ,A_n$ ​ from a Probability Condition
I am working on a problem involving independence of events in probability theory. The setup is as follows:
Let  $A_1,A_2, . . . ,A_n$ be events in a probability space. I am trying to prove that if the condition
$$P\left(\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}^{}A_i\right)\cap \left(\bigcap_{i\in [n]\backslash I}^{}A_i^c)\right)\right)=\prod_{i\in I}^{}P(A_i)\prod_{i\in [n]\backslash I}^{}P(A_i^c)$$
holds for all subsets $I\subseteq [n]$, then $A_1,A_2, . . . ,A_n$ are independent.
I have proved the converse: if $A_1,A_2, . . . ,A_n$ are independent, then the given condition holds. However, I am stuck on proving the reverse implication and would greatly appreciate guidance or an explanation. Thank you!

Let $p_i=\mathbb P(A_i)$. We have to show that for each subset $I$ of $[n]$, $\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right)=\prod_{i\in I}p_i$.
Let us fix such a set $I$. For $J\subset [n]\setminus I$, let $B_J:=
\bigcap_{j\in J}A_j\cap \bigcap_{k\in [n]\setminus (I\cup J)}A_k^c$. Then the sets $(B_J)_{J\subset [n]}$ form a partition of $\Omega$ hence
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\right)=\sum_{J\subset [n]\setminus I}\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\cap B_J\right). 
$$
Applying the assumption with $I$ replaced by $I\cup J$ shows that
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\cap B_J\right)=\prod_{i\in I}p_i\prod_{j\in J}p_j\prod_{k\in [n]\setminus (I\cup J)}(1-p_k).
$$
It remains to see that
$$
\sum_{J\subset [n]\setminus I}\prod_{j\in J}p_j\prod_{k\in [n]\setminus (I\cup J)}(1-p_k)=1,
$$
which follows from expansions of products of the form $\prod_{\ell\in [n]\setminus I}(a_\ell+b_\ell)$.

Thank you very much.
